# reprojectImageTo3D() typeError, OpenCV Python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I'm not able to use reprojectImageTo3D() using python in the latest openCV version.
I keep getting "TypeError: disparity is not a numpy array". It's an iplImage of course.

```
disparityImg = CreateImage( (320,240), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
depthMapImg = CreateImage( (320,240), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3)
depthMapImg = reprojectImageTo3D(disparityImg, Q)
```

But if I use an array for depthMapImg instead of an iplImage, I get "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (stype == CV_8UC1 || stype == CV_16SC1 || stype == CV_32SC1 || stype == CV_32FC1) in reprojectImageTo3D,..."

This latter error makes me think the data types aren't matching between the array and reprojectImageTo3D().

Neither works, what am i to do?

official reprojectImageTo3D() doc here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20reprojectImageTo3D%28InputArray%20disparity,%20OutputArray%20_3dImage,%20InputArray%20Q,%20bool%20handleMissingValues,%20int%20ddepth%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a sharp look : it's cv2.reprojectImageTo3D  (or, cv.Reproject...)

seems, you're trying to mix the  old (deprecated) cv api with the newer cv2 one. *don't* !

cv is using wrapped IplImages, cv2 is using numpy arrays

so, discard the old cv api, as it won't be supported in future versions. 
avoid any code, that's using iplimages

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks. Now i wonder if these functions ask for a list of tuples, or a straight up array, or what. It's never clear to me what form a function requires, and which index corresponds to rows, cols, etc. To anyone else who has the original issue, I had also taken the iplImage output from FindStereoCorrespondenceBM(), which is deprecated, and I couldn't see why the output was not compatible with cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(). Use the cv2 version of both.